# Transform pyspark dataframe to code / syntax

Tags: python, pyspark

Let's assume I've got the following pyspark dataframe in Databricks:

| some_other_column | price_history |
| --- | --- |
| test1 | [{"date":"2021-03-21T01:20:33Z","price_tag":"N","price":"9.23","price_promotion":"1.34","AKT":false,"my_column":null,"supplier":"some_supplier"}] |
| test2 | [{"date":"2021-03-23T01:20:33Z","price_tag":null,"price":"10.40","price_promotion":null,"AKT":true,"my_column":"something","supplier":null}] |

You can directly see that there is some nested column structure in the column "price_history". But how do I get the code to construct this table? Is there a way to transform this table to actual code which can then be used to create the table again?

The only way I know to get more information about the table is to use `df.schema` but the resulting schema does not tell me how to create dataframes that have complicated datastructures (like structs, maptype, arraytype, etc.) manually. If there is a way to get the code tests could be written much easier as example data could be created easily.

So what I'd like to get is the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

from pyspark.sql.types import (StructType, StructField, StringType,
                               ArrayType, TimestampType, BooleanType,
                               DecimalType)

schema = StructType([
    StructField("some_other_column", StringType()),
    StructField('price_history', ArrayType(StructType([
        StructField('date', TimestampType()),
        StructField('price_tag', StringType()),
        StructField('price', DecimalType(12, 2)),
        StructField('price_promotion', DecimalType(12, 2)),
        StructField('AKT', BooleanType()),
        StructField("my_column", StringType()),
        StructField("supplier", StringType()),
    ]))),
])

data = [
    ('test1', [(datetime(2021, 3, 21, 1, 20, 33), 'N',
                Decimal('9.23'), Decimal('1.34'), False, None, 'some_supplier')]),
    ('test2', [(datetime(2021, 3, 23, 1, 20, 33), None,
                Decimal('10.40'), None, True, 'something', None)]),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(schema=schema, data=data)
```

Comment: the question is not clear to me. What is the use case you are looking for and what is the input/output you are looking for?   Can you store the table as Parquet/JSON and read it with the schema you want?

Comment: @Emma: I'd like to use the code to create a test. Since my tests are run in docker container I don't want to copy files (parquets/jsons) to the container up front but I'd rather create the dataframes required for the test using syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I found an answer to the question! Pyspark's Rows can be used. Here are two functions that can be used to create code out of an incoming 'dataframe':

```
def create_column_mapping(columns: Iterable[str]) -> Dict[str, str]:
    """Create a mapping from old column names ('columns') to new column
       names that are accepted by pyspark.sql.Row. The things that are
       not accepted within column names:
       1. Spaces (' ')
       2. Minuses ('-')
       3. Slashes ('/')
       We just replace spaces by empty strings and minuses as well as slashes by underscores."""
    return {column: column.replace(' ', '') \
                          .replace('-', '_') \
                          .replace('/', '_')
            for column in columns}


def create_dataframe_code(dataframe: DataFrame) -> str:
    """Create databricks pyspark code that can be used to create
       'dataframe'."""
    # Create a mapping from existing column names to column
    # names that are compatible with creating rows (pyspark.sql.Row).
    mapping = create_column_mapping(dataframe.columns)
    df_mapped = dataframe.select(
        *[col(source_col).alias(target_col)
          for source_col, target_col in mapping.items()])
    # Create the syntax to create the dataframe and rename
    # to columns to their old names
    renaming = "".join([f".withColumnRenamed(existing='{target_col}', new='{source_col}')"
                        for source_col, target_col in mapping.items()
                        if source_col!=target_col])
    syntax = f"spark.createDataFrame({df_mapped.collect()}, schema={df_mapped.schema}){renaming}"
    # In case there single quotes ("'") are used within string columns all single quotes in
    # the syntax are replaced by "\'". We have to correct that.
    return syntax.replace(r"\'", "'")
```

To check whether things work out just use the syntax to recreate the dataframe (using 'eval') for which the code is created and to check whether it is the same as the incoming dataframe:

```
from pyspark.testing import assertDataFrameEqual  # (requires pyspark 3.5 and pyarrow)

test_dataframe = eval(create_dataframe_code(dataframe=example_dataframe))
assertDataFrameEqual(test_dataframe, example_dataframe)
```

In my cases that also included complicated columns like arrays of structs the function worked perfectly!

One important hint: To be able to execute he syntax created by `create_column_mapping` it sometimes requires to import some additional packages like `from numpy import nan` if there are missing floats in the original dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a solution to generate the code that builds you the table. Perhaps ChatGPT can help with that, but this is a sample for creating array of struct from flat columns:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import datetime

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

initial_df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ('test1', datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 8, 12), 'N'),
  ('test1', datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 8, 13, 30), 'Y'),
  ('test2', datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 8, 14), 'N')
], ['some_other_column', 'date', 'price_tag'])

refined_df = (
  initial_df
  .withColumn('price_detail', f.struct(*[f.col(element) for element in ['date', 'price_tag']]))
  .groupBy('some_other_column')
  .agg(f.collect_list(f.col('price_detail')).alias('price_history'))
)

refined_df.show(truncate = False)
refined_df.printSchema()
```

output:

```
+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------+        
|some_other_column|price_history                                       |
+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|test1            |[{2024-01-08 12:00:00, N}, {2024-01-08 13:30:00, Y}]|
|test2            |[{2024-01-08 14:00:00, N}]                          |
+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- some_other_column: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price_history: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- price_tag: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already know how to create an array of struct. Unfortunately, as you already said, this does not really answer the question. Probably there is no possibility to do what I want.